# Mongoose update validation of dynamically named nested value is failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble getting validation to work. Based on the following code, I am able to atomically update my `attribute` values, but **I never get any validation errors during `update()`**. If I save a value other than what is listed in my `enum` the document still saves.

I have the following schema defined in `Model.js`:

```
'use strict';

var db = require('./DbService');
var mongoose = db.Mongoose;

var Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    myId: { type: [String], index: { unique: true } },
    description: String,
    attributes: {
        speed: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['Fast','Moderate','Slow'],
        }],
        /* ... more attributes */
    }
});

exports.Model = mongoose.model('Model', Schema);
```

In a service, I have the following which should update an arbitrary `attributes` property.

```
'use strict';

var Model = require('./Model');

exports.modelFieldSET = function(args, response, next) {

    // args passed from path, ie: www.mysite.com/model/setField/{myId}/{field}/{value}
    var updateField = 'attributes.' + args.field.value;
    Model.Model.findOneAndUpdate({myId: args.myId.value},
    {
        $set: {
            [updateField]: args.value.value
        }
    },
    { new: true, context: 'query', runValidators: true },
    function(err, updateResponse){
        console.log(err);
        response.end(JSON.stringify(updateResponse, null, 4));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use `$push` to add a value to the array. `$set` is used to update fields.

The validation is against the array field `attributes.speed`.

So when you use `$set` the existing `attributes.speed` from array value is overwritten with a field value.

Change to

`$push: {[updateField]: args.value.value}`

Comment: Invariably, I find a quirk after posting a question. I noticed a couple obscure posts about arrays and you are correct. Alternatively, using `[updateField]: [args.value.value]` works as well but I'm going to have to add my own array handler I guess.